# How safe are ATR 72/42 planes?

Tags: atr-72, atr-42

I'm flying end of December and they seem to have issues with icing? Is this something I should be worried about? Thanks.

Comment: If they weren't safe they wouldn't be flying. "Safety first" is not just a catch phrase in aviation, it is how the entire aviation sector operates.

Comment: "Safety is our goal!  But let's be realistic."

Answer (score 6):

The ATR icing problem [was 25 years ago](https://www.flightglobal.com/atr-plans-modification-to-tackle-icing-issue-after-us-flight-tests/17489.article).  I'm sure you'll make it safely by this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a US commercial airline, then you have less chance of dying on a flight than you do doing anything else you can imagine, including sleeping in your bed at night. (A 75-year lifespan spends about 750,000 man-hours in bed, with one death in those hours.  The deaths-per-flight-hour rate for US airlines is between 1/10th and 1/100th of that.)

If the airplanes couldn't meet the safety standards of the FAA, they wouldn't be flying.

Comment: I am flying in Europe, also why did boeing 737 MAX meet the FAA and EASA standards then?

Comment: In Europe you can also be assured that the aircraft flying commercial routes are considered and proven safe. Icing is a well known fact of aviation and pilots and ground crews know how to manage it.

Comment: That's what you might call a Black Swan event with unique circumstances and decisions resulting in something tragic.  Doesn't change the overall risk level in the big picture.  There hasn't been a crash of a Heavy in the US in nearly 20 years.  There used to be one every couple of years a couple generations ago.  The ATR's had a problem with aileron reversal with ice on the leading edge after one rolled over and crashed many years ago.  It was fixed.  As the old saw goes, the drive to the airport is far more dangerous from a pure statistical risk perspective.

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea  The Max, even with the bad software, in the hands of competent pilots, was fine.  The problem with both Max crashes was that the pilots in both crews fell tragically short of the standards of experience & hand-flying competence to which American, and many European, crews are held to.  Depending on what airline you're on in Europe, you may be fine -- Lufthansa & British Airways are excellent.  Some from the Former Soviet Union, perhaps not as much.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm flying end of December and they seem to have issues with icing?

Remember that every single commercial aircraft flies every single day. Probably multiple flights per day. For most of these flights you're not on board, and don't care - but they still happen.

If an airliner crashes, it's headline news everywhere in the world. Thus we hear about pretty much every aircraft accident, no matter where it happens. I read about such things a couple of times per year - often a regional or commuter air line in some remote country. I've not read about major crashes in Europe this year.

Airline crashes simply doesn't happen, at least not in the western world. Whenever they happen they're basically a combination of multiple bad things at once, and more or less impossible to predict.